# What are the default accounts in version 12 of oracle db

Tags: oracle

What are the default accouints in version 12 of oracle db. (SYSTEM, etc.)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/admin/getting-started-with-database-administration.html#GUID-79AB6187-1522-4EB7-8FAD-E4322262AC65

Answer (score 3):

[Predefined User Accounts Provided by Oracle Database](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/tdpsg/securing-the-database-installation-and-configuration.html#GUID-9107985A-AA8A-4A81-A644-863884083AB7)

> **Predefined Oracle Database Administrative User Accounts**
>
> ANONYMOUS
>
> An account that allows HTTP access to Oracle XML DB. It is used in
>   place of the APEX_PUBLIC_USER account when the Embedded PL/SQL Gateway
>   (EPG) is installed in the database.
>
> EPG is a Web server that can be used with Oracle Database. It provides
>   the necessary infrastructure to create dynamic applications.
>
> Expired and locked
>
> AUDSYS
>
> The internal account used by the unified audit feature to store
>   unified audit trail records.
>
> See Oracle Database Security Guide.
>
> Expired and locked
>
> CTXSYS
>
> The account used to administer Oracle Text. Oracle Text enables you to
>   build text query applications and document classification
>   applications. It provides indexing, word and theme searching, and
>   viewing capabilities for text.
>
> See Oracle Text Application Developer's Guide.
>
> Expired and locked
>
> DBSNMP
>
> The account used by the Management Agent component of Oracle
>   Enterprise Manager to monitor and manage the database.
>
> See Enterprise Manager Cloud Control Administrator's Guide.
>
> Open
>
> Password is created at installation or database creation time.
>
> LBACSYS
>
> The account used to administer Oracle Label Security (OLS). It is
>   created only when you install the Label Security custom option.
>
> See Enforcing Row-Level Security with Oracle Label Security, and
>   Oracle Label Security Administrator’s Guide.
>
> Expired and locked
>
> MDSYS
>
> The Oracle Spatial and Oracle Multimedia Locator administrator
>   account.
>
> See Oracle Spatial and Graph Developer's Guide.
>
> Expired and locked
>
> OLAPSYS
>
> The account that owns the OLAP Catalog (CWMLite). This account has
>   been deprecated, but is retained for backward compatibility.
>
> Expired and locked
>
> ORDDATA
>
> This account contains the Oracle Multimedia DICOM data model. See
>   Oracle Multimedia DICOM Developer's Guide for more information.
>
> Expired and locked
>
> ORDPLUGINS
>
> The Oracle Multimedia user. Plug-ins supplied by Oracle and
>   third-party, format plug-ins are installed in this schema.
>
> Oracle Multimedia enables Oracle Database to store, manage, and
>   retrieve images, audio, video, DICOM format medical images and other
>   objects, or other heterogeneous media data integrated with other
>   enterprise information.
>
> See Oracle Multimedia User's Guide.
>
> Expired and locked
>
> ORDSYS
>
> The Oracle Multimedia administrator account.
>
> See Oracle Multimedia User's Guide.
>
> Expired and locked
>
> SI_INFORMTN_SCHEMA
>
> The account that stores the information views for the SQL/MM Still
>   Image Standard.
>
> See Oracle Multimedia User's Guide.
>
> Note: The SI_INFORMTN_SCHEMA account is deprecated in Oracle Database
>   12c release 2 (12.2).
>
> Expired and locked
>
> SYS
>
> An account used to perform database administration tasks.
>
> See Oracle Database 2 Day DBA.
>
> Open
>
> Password is created at installation or database creation time.
>
> SYSBACKUP
>
> The account used to perform Oracle Recovery Manager recovery and
>   backup operations.
>
> See Oracle Database Backup and Recovery User’s Guide.
>
> Expired and locked
>
> SYSDG
>
> The account used to perform Oracle Data Guard operations.
>
> See Oracle Data Guard Concepts and Administration.
>
> Expired and locked
>
> SYSKM
>
> The account used to manage Transparent Data Encryption.
>
> See Oracle Database Advanced Security Guide.
>
> Expired and locked
>
> SYSRAC
>
> The account used to manage Oracle Real Application Clusters.
>
> See Oracle Real Application Clusters Administration and Deployment
>   Guide.
>
> Expired and locked
>
> SYSTEM
>
> A default generic database administrator account for Oracle databases.
>
> For production systems, Oracle recommends creating individual database
>   administrator accounts and not using the generic SYSTEM account for
>   database administration operations.
>
> See Oracle Database 2 Day DBA.
>
> Open
>
> Password is created at installation or database creation time.
>
> WMSYS
>
> The account used to store the metadata information for Oracle
>   Workspace Manager.
>
> See Oracle Database Workspace Manager Developer's Guide.
>
> Expired and locked
>
> XDB
>
> The account used for storing Oracle XML DB data and metadata. For
>   better security, never unlock the XDB user account.
>
> Oracle XML DB provides high-performance XML storage and retrieval for
>   Oracle Database data.
>
> See Oracle XML DB Developer’s Guide.
>
> **Predefined Non-Administrative User Accounts**
>
> DIP
>
> The Oracle Directory Integration and Provisioning (DIP) account that
>   is installed with Oracle Label Security. This profile is created
>   automatically as part of the installation process for Oracle Internet
>   Directory-enabled Oracle Label Security.
>
> See Oracle Label Security Administrator’s Guide.
>
> Expired and locked
>
> MDDATA
>
> The schema used by Oracle Spatial for storing Geocoder and router
>   data.
>
> Oracle Spatial provides a SQL schema and functions that enable you to
>   store, retrieve, update, and query collections of spatial features in
>   an Oracle database.
>
> See Oracle Spatial and Graph Developer's Guide.
>
> Expired and locked
>
> ORACLE_OCM
>
> The account used with Oracle Configuration Manager. This feature
>   enables you to associate the configuration information for the current
>   Oracle Database instance with My Oracle Support. Then when you log a
>   service request, it is associated with the database instance
>   configuration information.
>
> See Oracle Database Installation Guide for your platform.
>
> Expired and locked
>
> SPATIAL_CSW_ADMIN_USR
>
> The Catalog Services for the Web (CSW) account. It is used by Oracle
>   Spatial CSW Cache Manager to load all record-type metadata and record
>   instances from the database into the main memory for the record types
>   that are cached.
>
> See Oracle Spatial and Graph Developer's Guide.
>
> Expired and locked
>
> SPATIAL_WFS_ADMIN_USR
>
> The Web Feature Service (WFS) account. It is used by Oracle Spatial
>   WFS Cache Manager to load all feature type metadata and feature
>   instances from the database into main memory for the feature types
>   that are cached.
>
> See Oracle Spatial and Graph Developer's Guide.
>
> Expired and locked
>
> XS$NULL
>
> An internal account that represents the absence of database user in a
>   session and the actual session user is an application user supported
>   by Oracle Real Application Security. XS$NULL has no privileges and
>   does not own any database object. No one can authenticate as XS$NULL,
>   nor can authentication credentials ever be assigned to XS$NULL.
>
> Expired and locked